# Initialisation of PublicClientApplication with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, onedrive

I'm trying to make an application with Xamarin.Forms, in which I need to access to OneDrive files.

When I try to create `PublicClientApplication`  object in my `app.cs` file  with the line

```
PublicClientApplication myApp = new PublicClientApplication(CLIENT_ID);
```

I obtain this error :

> "System.NullReferenceException : 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'"

The Microsoft.Identity.Client 1.1.0.0 package is well installed. I reference it in my `app.cd` file and I have registred my application on the Azure AD v2.0 portal and have obtained an ID.

Can someone explain me where my mistake is?